# how to get values in this array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
   [REVENUE AND GROSS PROFIT] => Array
    (
        [2010] => null
        [2011] => null
        [2012] => null
        [2013] => null
        [2014] => null
    )

[Total revenue] => Array
    (
        [2010] => 11611.00
        [2011] => 12971.00
        [2012] => 13654.00
        [2013] => 13373.00
        [2014] => 14427.00
    )

[OPERATING EXPENSES] => Array
    (
        [2010] => null
        [2011] => null
        [2012] => null
        [2013] => null
        [2014] => null
    )
)
```

In loop how to get the **REVENUE AND GROSS PROFIT,Total revenue** in one variable and year values in another variable

Kindly help me to fix this

thanks,

Comment: How exactly do you want your output to look like? Please clarify that properly.

Comment: something like [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) can help you I guess ..

Answer (score 0):

You schould make 2 foreach loops

`$result_array_1` will be array of keys and `$result_array_2` of values

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
  $result_array_1[] = $key;

  foreach($value as $ $val){
    $result_array_2[] = $val;
  }
}
```